# Using node js to generate webpages

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

im making a website using node js and sockets where players can play against each other in a simple canvas game.

So on the homepage, 2 players match which then makes a new object in the Games[] array located on the server which stores every detail about that game, lets say its checkers, it stores every position of each checker so the game can be recreated and stored eaisily.

I want to be able to generate a webpage for example mysite/game/623 which would simulate the 623rd game created. It would look back in the array and load up game 623 for any spectators so they could type in that url and it would go there.

i also want features like chat etc which i can do but would i need a html template for this? The generated webpage has to be able to send and recive data back and forth to the server but i cant wrap my head around how i would do this.

I wasnt looking to use any external librarys either. Im happy to use php if that would be eaiser but i figured if i can do it with node js i might aswell, thinking about it i can already visualise how i could do it with php so any advice, links to tutorials or any videos that give me an insight would be great. i couldnt find what i was looking for an thought i might have been searching for the wrong thing.

thanks :)

Comment: I think one of the strengths with node is the ease of which you can drop in external libraries, and why reinvent the wheel? I would at least check out [EJS](http://ejs.co/) or [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) before I started building some html generator from scratch. There are many others (for PHP as well). Node's express can render pug-files out of the box (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: oh if its just an npm install thats ok with me, im not that good at programming so when i think of external librarys i just think if i can do it in normal js i would but yeh thats fine, are these just librarys to make templates or would these do exacly what i wanted them to in my post?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: im not looking for code, just advice on the best way to go about doing something before investing my time into doing it wrong, as i said ive researched this but all i can find is how to generate webpages using php, ajax etc. sounds like you got abit of an ego trying to police this website when i need genuine help